# Jquery, Rails: Prevent a user from opening multiple inline forms on a page at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have multiple inline forms on a page that can be toggled. The page is specific to a given 'question' a user can submit, and other users can submit an 'answer', which is a form that can be toggled. Users can also submit comments on the question, its child answers, or other comments, and such comments are also posted via toggling an inline form.

However, some of my tests are failing (e.g. `Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching field "Answer Brief"`), presumably because there are no rules or preventions to toggling multiple forms at once.

How do I make users close a form before they can open a new one?

All of the forms I have are opened with a Rails link_to method calling the `new` action in the controller, which is a `new.js.erb` containing the toggling of the form and toggling of the link text conditions. e.g.:

`_answer.html.erb`:

`<%= link_to "Add comment", new_answer_comment_path(answer), id: "#{answer.id}", remote: true %>`

Which calls `new.js.erb` to render the form:

```
var selector = ".<%= j @commentable.class.to_s.downcase + '-' + @commentable.id.to_s + '  .media-body ' %>"
selector = selector + ".<%= j @commentable.class.to_s.downcase %>-comments"

if ($(selector + " .js-inline-form").length == 0) {
    $(" .js-inline-form").remove()
    $(selector)
        .append("<li class='js-inline-form'><%= j render :partial => 'comments/form' %></li>")
    $("#<%= j @commentable.id.to_s %>").text("Cancel")
}
else {
    $(" .js-inline-form").remove()
    if($("#<%= j @commentable.id.to_s %>").closest("li.media.comment.comment-<%= j @commentable.id.to_s %>").length > 0) {
        $("#<%= j @commentable.id.to_s %>").text("Reply to comment")
    }
    else {
        $("#<%= j @commentable.id.to_s %>").text("Add comment")
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: There is no "best way", this is entirely up to you to implement a solution. Either disable the ability to open new forms until the current one is closed, or automatically close any open forms when a new one is opened. We can't provide any useful insights based on what you've posted.

Comment: @meagar my question is how do I do it? I've already got a js.erb file attached to the link_to, how do I attach another one? Should I edit the `new.js.erb` file from every link to check if any others are open, or make a new js.erb file entirely - if the latter, how do I connect it to all the different events on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript that verifies if there is any open form. If it finds an open form, you can use preventDefault() to avoid the link from opening a new form.

This javascript could be hooked in your link_to click event.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how you would do it?

Comment: Also, its different links that open different forms that I'm worried about; not the same one opening multiple.